# Resort ArrayList of HashMaps a simple way

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

My app contains an ArrayList of HashMaps. The fetched data is sorted by distance. To reduce the queries, I want to resort the ArrayList. I searched and only found ways which suggest to create an own comparator. Is there a simpler way to do it? So like rearrange the HashMaps by value and not by distance and save them into a second ArrayList of HashMaps?

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("stores");

                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String dist = c.getString("dist");
                        String value = c.getString("value");

                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("dist", dist);
                        contact.put("value", value);

                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to resort the ArrayList. I searched and only found ways which suggest to create an own comparator. Is there a simpler way to do it?

To be clear, the suggestions you saw were surely to write a `Comparator` ***so as to be able to use `Collections.sort()` to perform the actual sorting***.

It's a lot simpler to implement just a mechanism for comparing two elements of your list than it would be to write the whole sort routine (which would still need to know how to compare elements).  You also have the alternative to use a custom subclass of `HashMap` that implements `Comparable`, but that would not be easier to prepare than a suitable `Comparator`, *and* you would need to ensure that it was actually used everywhere that elements are added to the list.

Now, it's not that hard to write a `Comparator` implementation from scratch, but these days you probably don't have to do that anyway.  The `Comparator` interface now has some static methods useful for building instances.  Thus, for your purpose, you could probably do something as simple as:

```
Collections.sort(contactList, Comparator.comparing(m -> Integer.valueOf(m.get("dist"))));
```

Note that you are indeed building and using a `Comparator` *instance* there, but you are spared from writing its class.  I don't think you can hope for much simpler than that.

Comment: Thank you so far! Would you explain to me what the "m" is in the collection sort method?

Comment: @user9582784, the expression `m -> Integer.valueOf(m.get("dist"))` is a [lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).  The compiler interprets it as defining an implementation of an instance of the *functional interface* that is the expected type of the corresponding method parameter.  This is the magic that allows you to avoid  writing a full-blown `Comparable` implementation class (not that that would be so much harder).

Comment: The `m` is the (in this case, single) parameter of the relevant functional interface's one instance method.

Comment: So to get it right, would I be needed to write another method to use it, or does your Collections.sort statement work on its own already?

Comment: @user9582784, the statement I gave should work on its own.

Comment: I get an error that comparing and .get cannot be resolved. Do I need to implement a certain interface for that?

Comment: My bad, @user9582784, I had a syntax error in my code, now fixed by changing `::` to `.` (instead of a method *reference*, I needed a method *invocation*).  The result tests successfully for me, but do be aware that lambdas and everything associated with them were new in Java 1.8.  If you are using an earlier Java version then you have no better alternative than implementing your own whole `Comparator` class (which, again, is not that hard).

Comment: It works like that too, the . did the trick indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One alternative that might make things simpler as compared to using `HashMaps`, is to create a class for `Contact` instead say :

```
public class Contact {

    private String id;
    private Double dist;
    private String value;

    public Contact(String id, Double dist, String value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.dist = dist;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // Omitting the setters for brevity 

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public Double getDist() {
        return this.dist;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Then in your code use an `ArrayList` of `Contacts`:

```
    List<Contact> contactList;

    // ... rest of the code

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("stores");

                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    Double dist = c.getDouble("dist"); // assuming dist is double
                    String value = c.getString("value");

                    contactList.add(new Contact(id, dist, value));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then sorting the collection:

```
contactList.sort(comparing(Contact::getDist));
```

Comment: Your suggestion works for me as well just fine, so I gave it the upvote!